# Создание символической ссылки (Symbolic Link) через групповые политики (GPO)

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Создаю политику на применение скрипта автозагрузки (политика на компьютер). Код скрипта:

```
mklink C:\log\cmd.link.exe C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe >> C:\log\symlink.log 2>&1
```

Распространяю на машины с Win7 32/64 бит, UAC везде отключён. В логе `C:\log\symlink.log` неизменно вижу ошибку "недостаточно привилегий для выполнения этой операции".

В чём может быть проблема? Гугл подсказывает только "запустить cmd от администратора", или прописать привилегии для всех на создание линков, но при запуске скрипта руками от администратора, или от системы (через `psexec -s -e`) всё работает. Проблема только при использовании с политикой.

Пробовал даже через PowerShell заворачивать (на всякий случай):

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:windir\system32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c mklink C:\log\cmd.link.exe C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe >> C:\log\symlink.txt 2>&1" -Verb RunAs
```

тоже не помогает - ошибка та же...

Может, есть какой-то аналог `mklink` для PowerShell? Мне сходу найти не удалось.

---

Добавил в скрипт строчку `whoami /all > C:\log\symlink.log 2>&1` по просьбе тов. **PetSerAl**. Вывод команды:

```
Сведения о пользователе
----------------

Пользователь         SID     
==================== ========
nt authority\система S-1-5-18


Сведения о группах
-----------------

Группа                                          Тип                     SID          Атрибуты                                                     
=============================================== ======================= ============ =============================================================
BUILTIN\Администраторы                          Псевдоним               S-1-5-32-544 Включены по умолчанию, Включенная группа, Владелец группы    
Все                                             Хорошо известная группа S-1-1-0      Обязательная группа, Включены по умолчанию, Включенная группа
NT AUTHORITY\Прошедшие проверку                 Хорошо известная группа S-1-5-11     Обязательная группа, Включены по умолчанию, Включенная группа
Обязательная метка\Обязательный уровень системы Метка                   S-1-16-16384                                                              


Сведения о привилегиях
----------------------

Имя привилегии                Описание                                    Область, край
============================= =========================================== =============
SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege Замена маркера уровня процесса              Отключен     
SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege      Настройка квот памяти для процесса          Отключен     
SeTcbPrivilege                Работа в режиме операционной системы        включен      
SeSecurityPrivilege           Управление аудитом и журналом безопасности  Отключен     
SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege      Смена владельцев файлов и других объектов   Отключен     
SeLoadDriverPrivilege         Загрузка и выгрузка драйверов устройств     Отключен     
SeCreatePermanentPrivilege    Создание постоянных общих объектов          включен      
SeBackupPrivilege             Архивация файлов и каталогов                Отключен     
SeRestorePrivilege            Восстановление файлов и каталогов           Отключен     
SeShutdownPrivilege           Завершение работы системы                   Отключен     
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege       Обход перекрестной проверки                 включен      
SeImpersonatePrivilege        Имитация клиента после проверки подлинности включен
```

Comment: Покажите вывод `whoami /all`, когда команда выполняется политикой.

Comment: @PetSerAl, добавил в пост.

Comment: Как видите, привилегия `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` действительно отсутствует. Надо смотреть в сторону назначения привилегий скриптам GPO. Любой аналог `mklink` будет выдавать туже ошибку без этой привилегии.

Comment: Как, интересно, можно назначить привилегии скрипту? Насколько мне известно, привилегию можно назначить только на учётку/группу. На данный момент права "Create Symbolic Links" назначены по умолчанию - группе Administrators, в которую Система, как видно из лога в посте, таки входит. Но почему отсутствует данный токен при выполнении именно из GPO - действительно, загадка... При выполнении через psexec от имени системы он есть.

Comment: Я предполагаю, что проблема связана с тем, что привилегия `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` не входит в список требуемых привилегий для службы "Клиент групповой политики": `sc qprivs gpsvc`, поэтому эта привилегия и не предоставляется скриптам групповой политики. Попробуйте добавить эту привилегию к списку требуемых.

Comment: @PetSerAl И правда! Оформите как ответ - помечу галочкой :) Если предварительно прописать `sc privs <CurrentPrivs>/SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` - ссылки создаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипты загрузки выполняются службой **Клиент групповой политики** (**gpsvc**) и имеют тот же набор привилегий, что и сама служба. По умолчанию, служба выполняется от имени системной учётной записи, однако служба задаёт список требуемых привилегий, и привилегия `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` в этот список не входит.

При запуске процесса службы привилегии, не указанные в списке требуемых для службы (для служб работающий в режиме `WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS` используется объединённый список от всех служб, которые могут работать в данном процессе), исключаются из токена процесса.

Таким образом, служба **gpsvc** не получает привилегию `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`, так как не запрашивает её. Скрипты групповой политики, которые запускает эта служба, также не получают данной привилегии, поэтому попытка создать символическую ссылку приводит к ошибке.

Для устранения ошибки необходимо добавить привилегию `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege` к списку требуемых для службы **gpsvc**. Сделать это можно при помощи консольной команды `sc` подкоманды `privs`:

```
C:\>sc privs
ОПИСАНИЕ.
        Изменение параметра необходимых привилегий для службы.
        Параметры привилегий вступают в силу, когда процесс службы запускается
        при запуске первой службы процесса. В этот момент диспетчер управления
        службами (SCM) определяет набор всех привилегий,  необходимых всем
        службам-участникам этого процесса, а затем создает процесс с такими
        привилегиями. Если данный параметр отсутствует, предполагается, что
        службе требуются все привилегии, разрешенные подсистемой безопасности
        для процесса, который выполняется от имени учетной записи, настроенной
        для этой службы.

ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЕ:
        sc <сервер> privs [имя службы] [привилегии]

ПАРАМЕТРЫ:
        привилегии = <Привилегии(разделенные косой чертой (/))>
                     [Например, SeBackupPrivilege/SeRestorePrivilege]
```